# Representation of limit of products of the fixed necklaces of length n composed of a types of beads

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, totient-function, necklace-and-bracelets

I failed to find a way how to prove the limit and how to get the approximation below. Actually the formula and the comment were publised at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163496/error-term-in-formula-for-products-of-necklaces/196153#196153) with no clear explanations.

In other words I'd like to represent the infinite products of necklaces in a way like below. Any ideas on that?

"Let us consider the $\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{p=1}^n N(p,a)$, where the number of fixed necklaces of length n composed of a types of beads $N(n,a)$ can be calculated via totient function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Necklace.html

It is possible to show that for large $n$:
$\frac {a^n} {n!} \prod_{p=1}^n \frac {1-a^p} {1-a}-\prod_{p=1}^n N(p,a) \le \frac {a^n} {n!} O(1/(n^{1/2-\epsilon})$

$\frac {(a-1)^{n+1}} {(a-3) \cdot n!} \prod_{p=1}^n \frac {1-a^p} {1-a}$ gives a much better approximation to $\prod_{p=1}^n N(p,a)$ with $n \to \infty$ for $a > 3$ "

Comment: The limit you talk about doesn't exist; the product diverges. From the second half of the post, it appears that what you're actually interested in is the asymptotic behaviour of the product.